# Ways of checking if record exists in itab without loop?

Tags: abap

Is there a shortcut or should I just loop at the table and check?

I mean I am using an internal table and I want to check if a value is contained in one field of the internal table and I don't want to loop the table to find the value. Is it possible?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To check for a specific value without doing a loop or transferring values to a work area, you can use the `READ` statement with the addition `TRANSPORTING NO FIELDS` like so:

```
READ TABLE itab WITH KEY FIELD = 'X' TRANSPORTING NO FIELDS.
IF sy-subrc = 0.
  "Read was successful.
ENDIF.
```

**UPDATE**: From release 740 ABAP contains the predicate function `LINE_EXISTS` which is described [in this blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/06/22/abap-news-for-release-740-new-internal-table-functions/).

It's a built-in function to which you pass a table expression. Using the above example:

```
IF line_exists( itab[ field = 'X' ] ).
  "Do stuff
ENDIF.
```

Full syntax of table expression in that predicate see here: https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abentable_expressions.htm

Comment: Keep in mind you can (and probably should) use binary search to speed this up.

Comment: And if itab has no field names, use `[ table_line = 'X' ]`

Answer (score 2):

Selam,

If you are going to use loop in your algorithm, then you can use something like this:

```
LOOP ITAB WHERE FIELD = 'X'.

"code sample

ENDLOOP.
```

If you are not going to use a loop in your code, then i don't think there is a specific way to check for a specific value in itab.

Hope its helpful.

Talha

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer, this is incorrect.  You can check for the existence of a record without a loop.

Comment: A search with a loop is slow, dont use this.